# How to capture all repitions of a subpattern in regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a formatted string, that can have a repeated part of arbitrary length. For example, here is an example of the metadata I have that I want to parse.

```
File Name: chb03_34.edf
File Start Time: 01:51:23
File End Time: 2:51:23
Number of Seizures in File: 1
Seizure Start Time: 1982 seconds
Seizure End Time: 2029 seconds

File Name: chb23_07.edf
File Start Time: 11:03:16
File End Time: 11:45:56
Number of Seizures in File: 0

File Name: chb23_08.edf
File Start Time: 11:48:05
File End Time: 14:40:27
Number of Seizures in File: 2
Seizure 1 Start Time: 325 seconds
Seizure 1 End Time: 345 seconds
Seizure 2 Start Time: 5104 seconds
Seizure 2 End Time: 5151 seconds

File Name: chb23_09.edf
File Start Time: 14:40:47
File End Time: 18:41:13
Number of Seizures in File: 4
Seizure 1 Start Time: 2589 seconds
Seizure 1 End Time: 2660 seconds
Seizure 2 Start Time: 6885 seconds
Seizure 2 End Time: 6947 seconds
Seizure 3 Start Time: 8505 seconds
Seizure 3 End Time: 8532 seconds
Seizure 4 Start Time: 9580 seconds
Seizure 4 End Time: 9664 seconds
```

So far I've created a regex that captures the first lines, but can only capture the last seizure, if a seizure exists, in a block.

```
import re

summary = "a formatted string read"


pattern = "File Name\: (.+)\nFile Start Time\: (.+)\nFile End Time\: (.+)\nNumber of Seizures in File\: (.+)(?:\n|\r|)(?:Seizure(?: | \d )Start Time\: (\d+) seconds\nSeizure(?: | \d )End Time\: (\d+) seconds(?:\n|\r|))*"
pattern = re.compile(pattern)

for p in pattern.finditer(summary):
    print(p.groups())
```

But the result of such pattern for the last block for example will only capture the seizure 4 start and end time. Is it possible to capture a repeated subpattern recursively?

EDIT: using `regex` and the pattern  [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird) has typed in the comments, I can match the strings, but I get a lot of None values in repeated rows, and also completely None rows. How can I get rid of those, or insert the appropriate value?

```
('chb23_06.edf', '08:57:57', '11:02:43', '1', '3962', '4075')
(None, None, None, None, None, None)
('chb23_07.edf', '11:03:16', '11:45:56', '0', None, None)
(None, None, None, None, None, None)
('chb23_08.edf', '11:48:05', '14:40:27', '2', '325', '345')
(None, None, None, None, '5104', '5151')
(None, None, None, None, None, None)
('chb23_09.edf', '14:40:47', '18:41:13', '4', '2589', '2660')
(None, None, None, None, '6885', '6947')
(None, None, None, None, '8505', '8532')
(None, None, None, None, '9580', '9664')
(None, None, None, None, None, None)
('chb23_10.edf', '18:41:40', '22:41:40', '0', None, None)
(None, None, None, None, None, None)
('chb23_16.edf', '13:46:32', '17:46:32', '0', None, None)
(None, None, None, None, None, None)
('chb23_17.edf', '17:46:42', '21:16:29', '0', None, None)
(None, None, None, None, None, None)
('chb23_19.edf', '02:28:28', '6:28:28', '0', None, None)
(None, None, None, None, None, None)
('chb23_20.edf', '06:28:36', '7:52:05', '0', None, None)
(None, None, None, None, None, None)
```

EDIT2: I did the solution of the previously accepted answer, but it has some rough edges and is not working in some files. I've uploaded one of the problematic files. You can find a paste of a sample of the problematic metadata in [here](https://pastebin.com/B6QLqtxS).

Comment: You get the None values due to the alternation `|` in the pattern. You can filter the None values from the result, or you can use a different approach by using your initial pattern, and capturing all the repeated rows at the end in a single groups that contain the Seizure values, and then for that group use split to get the separate values.

Comment: You should add your code where you actually "run" the regex to the question.

Comment: @FarhoodET I think [this approach](https://tio.run/##lZRfb4IwFMXf@RQ3PLVuI/SfYpPFp@3RF/doYlCqkkghBZO5L8@A4QBlA3lqT8/pvfeX0OSSHWPN8jyMkthkYNRBfYKfQrGyrMTPMmU0vIKx38OTgqUfKQnIecJrXQmrzC9SH@GN/KaDjrg8R1tlIN7DSoVfZ6NSCDWU1h8HQgu51vUZlJsA8KJ9@Tp4glTtYh2k98amXMuGJ9i2rPQcRb65FCOg9gi749ZlG8YdFezX2obWZ7U3NxnKNq5XZ3p87YYJkdyTruh3Nh0TLrkr6ezO9x8zeue@IiGdJhgVDbU/E00zjA/7aaeCIC4fEWlKCCJIE@in0@E9H8m74shng7w9yYkk7CHefCRvKrz5Q8DpdOo@SHzqeeIh4tM5nw0GWKeGJ1wxItLU8ASjrQDuvB3K2cVRUoBEtVgc72MDUQm4lpx9qIOwWKH6j8WyqpqYUGcocg4mPieIYNyj0l6V9aq8oxatlXX90wmZ37nKN6SC4Uyap6YUi3Gdif0M17sE7lxmvwx@Ns7zbw) it easier

Comment: Have you considered just reading the file line by line instead of a regex and building your data set that way? Though it seems you about have your working answer between these two answers.

Comment: @Jarvis yeah but that way is harder to actually piece together the metadata for each file. The answer I've accpeted now is completely ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `re`, you can capture the optional iterations of the Seizure strings in a group, and then from that group capture the digit values for the seconds:

Pattern

```
File Name: (.+)\nFile Start Time: (.+)\nFile End Time: (.+)\nNumber of Seizures in File: (.+)((?:\nSeizure (?:\d )?Start Time: \d+ seconds\nSeizure (?:\d )?End Time: \d+ seconds)*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `File Name: (.+)\n` **Group 1**, match all after File Name: and a newline
- `File Start Time: (.+)\n` **Group 2**, match all after File Start Time: and a newline
- `File End Time: (.+)\n` **Group 3**, match all after File End Time: and a newline
- `Number of Seizures in File: (.+)` **Group 4**, match all after Number of Seizures in File:
- `(` **Group 5**

  - `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole and then optionally repeat

    - `\nSeizure (?:\d )?Start Time: \d+ seconds\n` Match a newline and match the Seizure Start Time and a newline at the end
    - `Seizure (?:\d )?End Time: \d+ seconds` Match the Seizure End Time
  - `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `)` Close group 5

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W4UCOz/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##jVRNb9wgFDzXv@LJJ2hai08vRqpyao@5pMeVImfNJpbW2MJeqemf37LJbg2JP8IJzxveMAOmexmeW8tPp7rpWjeAM0/mD5Q9@FmSdOUwGGfhB7j0V30wcFc2RgPKbvDWvgL3Q@lX/a7fwT9tFYF3x@bROGj3cG/qv0dneqgtnKlvDIRu9dZeanD@qADfhs231Q30Ztfaqv9IHOUCGv6K0yTpj01TuhdvAYUWds@PhD9wkZlqv7Vp8iX9YIdQLalmPCiPOiysLbmjb5TrjkMBWig2egpZgQ5hxcgJtvLfBuMPZLNgg1JNuKb5pA1fFFLLfN0HmVdXy@pCaSKn1YUWRLPNujqL86GRBmdyOkYaaHExQ2JRL0mJmOONzSSVdP1UiqVcXq2LzXQuSguq6Sdul1jKhUlVrAfD8px8JplcKbmeTF6IzTSLR92UJHKON3ZTks/8ISLqVkhF5nhjtyLPRXhqnomjN85ku7bpfLDoAvryvnXQnAO/QNm@tlXtZ@jysmCdgB@dq@2AmuzJtccOUYwnUDaJ8klURKjf2lm3PByQS5F/5PDVSPoNrkskjtak31dHik@nfw)

For example

```
pattern = re.compile(pattern)

for m in pattern.finditer(summary):
    print(m.group(1))
    print(m.group(2))
    print(m.group(3))
    print(m.group(4))
    print(re.findall(r"(\d+) seconds", m.group(5)))
```

The output per match would look like: (or an empty list when there are no Seizure values, but you can test for that as well)

```
chb23_08.edf
11:48:05
14:40:27
2
['325', '345', '5104', '5151']
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, the answers given in this post indeed do not work for all the metadata I have, and I have run into some problematic files, I've edited my post again. If you could look at it again I would be so grateful.

Comment: @FarhoodET There seem to be occurrences with multiple whitespaces. See this regex for the first match https://regex101.com/r/p5zyE8/1 and this regex for the second match https://regex101.com/r/CV2umn/1 to match 1 or more whitespace characters.

Comment: @FarhoodET Using `\s+` can also match newlines, if you want to match whitespace chars wiithout newlines only, you can use `[^\S\n]+` instead

Comment: So which positions should I change? Should I change all whitespaces to multiple?

Comment: @FarhoodET If you know for certain parts that there is a single space, then you don't have to change those positions. See this example changing all positions https://ideone.com/bOMUVu

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module, I would suggest using repeated captures.

I've also added named groups for clarity:

```
import regex

pattern = regex.compile(
    r"File Name: (?P<name>.+)\n"
    r"File Start Time: (?P<start>.+)\n"
    r"File End Time: (?P<end>.+)\n"
    r"Number of Seizures in File: (?P<count>\d+)\n"
    r"(?:\n|(?:Seizure (?:\d )?Start Time: (?P<seizure_start>\d+) seconds\n"
    r"Seizure (?:\d )?End Time: (?P<seizure_end>\d+) seconds\n)*)"
)

summary = """File Name: chb03_34.edf
File Start Time: 01:51:23
File End Time: 2:51:23
Number of Seizures in File: 1
Seizure Start Time: 1982 seconds
Seizure End Time: 2029 seconds

File Name: chb23_07.edf
File Start Time: 11:03:16
File End Time: 11:45:56
Number of Seizures in File: 0

File Name: chb23_08.edf
File Start Time: 11:48:05
File End Time: 14:40:27
Number of Seizures in File: 2
Seizure 1 Start Time: 325 seconds
Seizure 1 End Time: 345 seconds
Seizure 2 Start Time: 5104 seconds
Seizure 2 End Time: 5151 seconds

File Name: chb23_09.edf
File Start Time: 14:40:47
File End Time: 18:41:13
Number of Seizures in File: 4
Seizure 1 Start Time: 2589 seconds
Seizure 1 End Time: 2660 seconds
Seizure 2 Start Time: 6885 seconds
Seizure 2 End Time: 6947 seconds
Seizure 3 Start Time: 8505 seconds
Seizure 3 End Time: 8532 seconds
Seizure 4 Start Time: 9580 seconds
Seizure 4 End Time: 9664 seconds
"""

for match in pattern.finditer(summary):
    print("Name:", match.group("name"))
    print("Seizure Count", match.group("count"))
    seizures = tuple(
        zip(match.captures("seizure_start"),match.captures("seizure_end")))
    for i, (start, end) in enumerate(seizures, start=1):
        print(f"Seizure #{i}: {start} -> {end}")
```

Prints:

```
Name: chb03_34.edf
Seizure Count 1
Seizure #1: 1982 -> 2029
Name: chb23_07.edf
Seizure Count 0
Name: chb23_08.edf
Seizure Count 2
Seizure #1: 325 -> 345
Seizure #2: 5104 -> 5151
Name: chb23_09.edf
Seizure Count 4
Seizure #1: 2589 -> 2660
Seizure #2: 6885 -> 6947
Seizure #3: 8505 -> 8532
Seizure #4: 9580 -> 9664
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry to bother you again, but the solution you've given me is not exactly working. I've uploded a sample file for you to look at, you can find it in the edited post.